# Read tables with different form in R

Tags: r

I am still on a basic beginner level with r. my file contains multiple tables, with different form and I would like to convert these tables in data frames the first 4  tables have the same name of variables. the last 4 tables have a with form and i would like to extract these in a large form and convert them into data frames (8 data frames ).

```
> dput(myfirstdt)
c("     Value    Meaning Cases Fraction", "     -0.95197 18-24   643   34.11%", 
"     -0.07854 25-34   481   25.52%", "      0.49788 35-44   356   18.89%", 
"      1.09449 45-54   294   15.60%", "      1.82213 55-64    93    4.93%", 
"      2.59171 65+      18    0.95%", "     Value    Meaning Cases Fraction", 
"      0.48246 Female  942   49.97%", "     -0.48246 Male    943   50.03%", 
"     Value    Meaning                                              Cases Fraction", 
"     -2.43591 Left school before 16 years                           28    1.49%", 
"     -1.73790 Left school at 16 years                               99    5.25%", 
"     -1.43719 Left school at 17 years                               30    1.59%", 
"     -1.22751 Left school at 18 years                              100    5.31%", 
"     -0.61113 Some college or university, no certificate or degree 506   26.84%", 
"     -0.05921 Professional certificate/ diploma                    270   14.32%", 
"      0.45468 University degree                                    480   25.46%", 
"      1.16365 Masters degree                                       283   15.01%", 
"      1.98437 Doctorate degree                                      89    4.72%", 
"     Value    Meaning             Cases Fraction", "     -0.09765 Australia             54   2.86%", 
"      0.24923 Canada                87   4.62%", "     -0.46841 New Zealand            5   0.27%", 
"     -0.28519 Other                118   6.26%", "      0.21128 Republic of Ireland   20   1.06%", 
"      0.96082 UK                  1044  55.38%", "     -0.57009 USA                  557  29.55%", 
"     Value    Meaning           Cases Fraction", "     -0.50212 Asian               26   1.38%", 
"     -1.10702 Black               33   1.75%", "      1.90725 Mixed-Black/Asian    3   0.16%", 
"      0.12600 Mixed-White/Asian   20   1.06%", "     -0.22166 Mixed-White/Black   20   1.06%", 
"      0.11440 Other               63   3.34%", "     -0.31685 White             1720  91.25%", 
"     Nscore Cases Value         Nscore Cases Value         Nscore Cases Value", 
"     12      1    -3.46436      29     60    -0.67825      46     67    1.02119", 
"     13      1    -3.15735      30     61    -0.58016      47     27    1.13281", 
"     14      7    -2.75696      31     87    -0.46725      48     49    1.23461", 
"     15      4    -2.52197      32     78    -0.34799      49     40    1.37297", 
"     16      3    -2.42317      33     68    -0.24649      50     24    1.49158", 
"     17      4    -2.34360      34     76    -0.14882      51     27    1.60383", 
"     18     10    -2.21844      35     69    -0.05188      52     17    1.72012", 
"     19     16    -2.05048      36     73     0.04257      53     20    1.83990", 
"     20     24    -1.86962      37     67     0.13606      54     15    1.98437", 
"     21     31    -1.69163      38     63     0.22393      55     11    2.12700", 
"     22     26    -1.55078      39     66     0.31287      56     10    2.28554", 
"     23     29    -1.43907      40     80     0.41667      57      6    2.46262", 
"     24     35    -1.32828      41     61     0.52135      58      3    2.61139", 
"     25     56    -1.19430      42     77     0.62967      59      5    2.82196", 
"     26     57    -1.05308      43     49     0.73545      60      2    3.27393", 
"     27     65    -0.92104      44     51     0.82562", "     28     70    -0.79151      45     37     0.91093", 
"     Escore Cases Value         Escore Cases Value         Escore Cases Value", 
"     16      2    -3.27393      31      55   -1.23177      45     91    0.80523", 
"     18      1    -3.00537      32      52   -1.09207      46     69    0.96248", 
"     19      6    -2.72827      33      77   -0.94779      47     64    1.11406", 
"     20      3    -2.53830      34      68   -0.80615      48     62    1.28610", 
"     21      3    -2.44904      35      58   -0.69509      49     37    1.45421", 
"     22      8    -2.32338      36      89   -0.57545      50     25    1.58487", 
"     23      5    -2.21069      37      90   -0.43999      51     34    1.74091", 
"     24      9    -2.11437      38     106   -0.30033      52     21    1.93886", 
"     25      4    -2.03972      39     107   -0.15487      53     15    2.12700", 
"     26     21    -1.92173      40     130    0.00332      54     10    2.32338", 
"     27     23    -1.76250      41     116    0.16767      55      9    2.57309", 
"     28     23    -1.63340      42     109    0.32197      56      2    2.85950", 
"     29     32    -1.50796      43     105    0.47617      58      1    3.00537", 
"     30     38    -1.37639      44     103    0.63779      59      2    3.27393", 
"     Oscore Cases Value         Oscore Cases Value         Oscore Cases Value", 
"     24      2    -3.27393      38      64   -1.11902      50     83    0.58331", 
"     26      4    -2.85950      39      60   -0.97631      51     87    0.72330", 
"     28      4    -2.63199      40      68   -0.84732      52     87    0.88309", 
"     29     11    -2.39883      41      76   -0.71727      53     81    1.06238", 
"     30      9    -2.21069      42      87   -0.58331      54     57    1.24033", 
"     31      9    -2.09015      43      86   -0.45174      55     63    1.43533", 
"     32     13    -1.97495      44     101   -0.31776      56     38    1.65653", 
"     33     23    -1.82919      45     103   -0.17779      57     34    1.88511", 
"     34     25    -1.68062      46     134   -0.01928      58     19    2.15324", 
"     35     26    -1.55521      47     107    0.14143      59     13    2.44904", 
"     36     39    -1.42424      48     116    0.29338      60      7    2.90161", 
"     37     51    -1.27553      49      98    0.44585", "     Ascore Cases Value         Ascore Cases Value         Ascore Cases Value", 
"     12      1    -3.46436      34      42   -1.34289      48     104   0.76096", 
"     16      1    -3.15735      35      45   -1.21213      49      85   0.94156", 
"     18      1    -3.00537      36      62   -1.07533      50      68   1.11406", 
"     23      1    -2.90161      37      83   -0.91699      51      58   1.2861", 
"     24      2    -2.78793      38      82   -0.76096      52      39   1.45039", 
"     25      1    -2.70172      39     102   -0.60633      53      36   1.61108", 
"     26      7    -2.53830      40      98   -0.45321      54      36   1.81866", 
"     27      7    -2.35413      41     114   -0.30172      55      16   2.03972", 
"     28      8    -2.21844      42     101   -0.15487      56      14   2.23427", 
"     29     13    -2.07848      43     105   -0.01729      57       8   2.46262", 
"     30     18    -1.92595      44     118    0.13136      58       7   2.75696", 
"     31     24    -1.77200      45     112    0.28783      59       1   3.15735", 
"     32     30    -1.62090      46     100    0.43852      60       1   3.46436", 
"     33     34    -1.47955      47     100    0.59042                  ", 
"     Cscore Cases Value         Cscore Cases Value         Cscore Cases Value", 
"     17      1    -3.46436      32       39  -1.25773      46     113   0.58489", 
"     19      1    -3.15735      33       49  -1.13788      47      95   0.7583", 
"     20      3    -2.90161      34       55  -1.01450      48      95   0.93949", 
"     21      2    -2.72827      35       55  -0.89891      49      76   1.13407", 
"     22      5    -2.57309      36       69  -0.78155      50      47   1.30612", 
"     23      5    -2.42317      37       81  -0.65253      51      43   1.46191", 
"     24      6    -2.30408      38       77  -0.52745      52      34   1.63088", 
"     25      9    -2.18109      39       87  -0.40581      53      28   1.81175", 
"     26     13    -2.04506      40       97  -0.27607      54      27   2.04506", 
"     27     13    -1.92173      41       99  -0.14277      55      13   2.33337", 
"     28     25    -1.78169      42      105  -0.00665      56       8   2.63199", 
"     29     24    -1.64101      43       90   0.12331      57       3   3.00537", 
"     30     29    -1.51840      44      111   0.25953      59       1   3.46436", 
"     31     41    -1.38502      45      111   0.41594                  "
)
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of `dput(dta)` in the question?

Comment: Is the number of rows in each table known? Or does it have to be figured out from the data? You could do `sapply(strsplit(dta, " "), length)` ... then applying run length encoding to it (`rle`) and by this, find the rows with equal numbers of columns. Then split your `dta` using this input, and finally convert each of these pieces into data frames. Is this what you need? I could elaborate it later if you need or you can probably work it out on your own.

Comment: @lebatsnok i give the original data i want to extract the 8 tables and convert them into a data frame

Comment: Can you count on variable names always being the same in each subtable?  E.g., the first variable is "Value" in first few cases, and then "Nscore", "Escore", "Oscore" etc.

Comment: Secondly, can you cont on columns having equal width? There is no "field separator" in your table but the widths seem to be fixed (so it can be read with `read.fwf` ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first approximation:

```
splits <- strsplit(dta," ")
splits <- lapply(splits, function(x) x[x!=""])
eql <- rle(sapply(splits, length))
eql$values <- LETTERS[seq_len(length(eql$values))]
divided <- split(dta, inverse.rle(eql))
lapply(divided, function(.) read.table(text=.))
```

... which outputs:

$A

```
    V1 V2
1    A Ba
2    1 55
3    3 78
4    4 99
5    A Ba
6   11 33
7   56 58
8    A Ba
9  0.6  m
10 0.5  f

$B
  V1  V2 V3 V4  V5  V6 V7  V8 V9
1 ns  bs cs ns  bs  cs ns  bs cs
2 12 0.5 11 15 0,8  99 18 1,4 33
3 13 0.9 13 16 0,7  10 19 1,1 44
4 14 0.6 33 17 0,4  33 20   3 56
5 os  bs cs os  bs  cs os  bs cs
6 13  11 22 20  77 0.5 26   4 33
7 14   6  1 21 0.8   1 27  55  5
8 15   5  3 22   1  33 28  44  6

$C
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1 17 44  5 23  4 66
2 18  3 13 24  5  7
3 19  5 33 25  5 66
```

Notice a couple of things. First, `$A` seems to contain three data frames, rows 1-4, rows 5-7, and rows 8-10. Or maybe not. And `$B` seems to contain two. So 3+2+1 = 6, which is one too many, as you said you've got 5. In addition, `$A` and `$B` seem to have names but not `$C`. Which means that you need to be a bit more specific as to how your data are structured. How do you tell where one piece of data ends and the other one starts? Are lines 1,5,8,11,15 supposed to be names of the variables? So that each of these lines starts a new segment of data? Or not?

....

with your new data set, the picture looks different. I would start with something like this:

```
firsts  <- sapply(strsplit(trimws(d2, "left"), " "), head, 1)
# the first "words" of each row
splitit <- split(d2, cumsum(firsts %in% c("Value", "Nscore", "Escore", "Oscore", "Ascroe")))
# sort the rows into sub-tables
```

Then I would continue with something like

```
mapply(read.fwf, splitit, widths=W)
```

where W is a list of vectors with column widths for each subtable.